# vectorized sum of array according to indices of second array

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization

I have an empty array:

```
empty = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

an array of indices corresponding to positions in my array empty

```
ind = np.array([2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

and an array of values

```
val = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I want to add the values in 'val' into 'empty' according to position given by 'ind'.

The non-vectorized solution is:

```
for i, v in zip(ind, val): maps[i] += v
>>> maps
[ 0.  4.  5.  1.  2.]
```

My actual arrays are multidimensional and loooong so i've got a **NEED FOR SPEED** I really want a vectorized solution, or a solution that is very fast.

Note this does not work:

```
maps[ind] += val
>>> maps
array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

I'd be extra grateful for a solution that works in python 2.7, 3.5, 3.6 with no hiccups

Comment: it's true it is a duplicate. but my question title is much more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of  [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) which operates equivalent to `empty[ind] += val`, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once giving you a cumulated outcome for those indices.

```
>>> np.add.at(empty, ind, val)
>>> empty
array([0, 4, 5, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `e=np.bincount(ind, weights=val, minlength=n)` where `n` is the length of your empty array.  That way you don't have to initialize `empty`.  You only need to do this the first time, as afterward you can do `e+=np.bincount(ind, weights=val)`

This is at least twice as fast as `np.add.at`:

```
%timeit np.bincount(ind, val, minlength=empty.size)
The slowest run took 12.69 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 µs per loop

%timeit np.add.at(empty, ind, val)
The slowest run took 2822.05 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.32 µs per loop
```

As for multi-dimensional indices, you can do:

```
np.bincount(np.ravel_multi_index(ind, empty.shape), np.ravel(val), minlength=empty.size).reshape(empty.shape)
```

I'm not sure how to do this with `np.add.at` to compare speeds

Comment: Should this work if empty and val are multidimensional? Ex: empty.shape = (5,2,2) and val.shape = (10,2,2)?

Comment: Not as written, you'd need to `ravel_multi_index` your indices, `ravel` `empty` and `val`, and `reshape` the end results.  At that point `np.add.at` is probably faster, or at least more pythonic.  But that's not what you asked :)

Comment: It is not what I asked, you are right. I didnt expect it would matter. But thanks!

Comment: Added an implementation with `bincount`.  I couldn't get `np.add.at` to take multiple indices, do you have a working code for it?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), so in the one-dimensional case:

```
h, b = np.histogram(ind, bins=np.arange(empty.size+1), weights=val)
empty += h
```

Of course you can leave out the second statement in case empty only has zeros.

Comment: I removed the part about `np.bincount`, because @DanielForsman already gave that answer, and I only saw after editing.